# Rewrite rules and let abstraction in GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
{-# RULES
"modify/fusedModify" forall f g key book. modify key f (modify key g book) = fusedModify key f g book
  #-}
```

Which fires in the following function:

```
pb :: PersonB
pb = ...

fusionB' :: PersonB
fusionB' =
  let l x = (modify #name ('c':) (modify #name ('a':) x))
  in l pb
```

However, without let (and presumably let-abstraction?) it does not fire:

```
fusionB :: PersonB
fusionB = modify #name ('c':) (modify #name ('a':) pb)
```

If it went the *other* way - that is, if the let-abstracted version didn't cause a firing, but `fusionB` did - I think I'd understand. It could be that in the specific case, `fusedModify` has the right type signature, but in the general (more polymorphic) case, it doesn't. But why in the world am I seeing this?

For what it's worth, the definition of `fusedModify` is [here](https://github.com/turingjump/bookkeeper/blob/fusion/bookkeeper/src/Bookkeeper/Internal.hs#L127), and the file with `fusionB` and `fusionB'` is [here](https://github.com/turingjump/bookkeeper/blob/fusion/bookkeeper/bench/Main.hs). I've tried `unsafeCoercing` type equalities to get both signatures to match up (in reality, though GHC doesn't realize it, they do always match), but somehow that doesn't help either.

*EDIT*: I should perhaps mention that I'm using GHC 8.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried using `INLINE CONLIKE [1]` for modify to delaying the inlining of modify until after the rule fires?

Comment: @Alec I just used `NOINLINE` to be sure inlining wasn't the issue. But I tried `INLINE CONLIKE [1]` just now and it doesn't help.

Comment: I am surprised that `l` does not get inlined even before the rule fires, and then the code would look equal. I guess you will have to look closer at the Core, both of the code and of the LHS of the rule.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner the core for `fusionB` is [here](https://gist.github.com/jkarni/828065f3f9fdfce998f91bc91b7b155e#file-core-L318-L346). Happy to paste the core for `fusionB'` too (the one in which the rule fires), though I'm not sure how that helps figure out why the rule doesn't fire in this case.

Comment: It has floated out stuff to the top-level, which often prevents rule from firing. Can you make `pb` an argument of `fusionB`?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner yes, and that helps (if I don't give it a signature), but I'd like this to fire reliably, since it's part of a library's API.

Comment: That seems to be a largely unsolved problem, unfortunately.